# Starting only file in a folder

Tags: command-line, scripts

Im currently using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
vblank_mode=0 /home/me/Documents/FileFolder/myfile-3.6.AppImage
```

But everytime the software updates itself the file name changes to something like myfile-4.0.AppImage, so I need a script to run the only file within the FileFolder folder.
Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: The solution is to isolate the file within a folder and change the 2nd line of the script to:
`for file in /home/me/Documents/FileFolder/*.AppImage; do vblank_mode=0 "$file"; done`

Comment: No need for a loop: it probably will work already with /home/me/Documents/FileFolder/myfile-*.AppImage, so isolating in a specific folder will not be needed if that name is unique enough *and* if old versions are immediately removed or moved out.